# Prettier: optional chaining support

Tags: prettier, optional-chaining

Vs code > OUTPUT > Prettier

```
2/23/2020, 12:10:36 PM:
-----------------------
Expression expected. (/Users/yanivper/dev/test/test.ts:2:23)
1 | function test(obj) {
2 |          return obj.a?.b;
                          ^
```

In a new project:

```
npm i typescript
```

VScode use Workstation Version 3.8.2 (shown in the left-bottom bar TypeScript 3.8.2 )
Prettier v 2.2.2

Answer (score 13):

In my case I resolve by update prettier from 1.18.2 to 2.0.5.

If someone here is using JetBrains based IDE, please check your prettier settings in IDE, make sure the "Prettier package" is set to right path but not older version path in your global package.

Comment: I started creating an issue myself just to post this answer. Turns out all that was needed was a `npm install -g prettier` to update to latest - which adds optional chaining support (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

Comment: Additionally, I had to restart VSCode (reload window) after updating prettier.